# iOS OpenGL ES 2.0 Shader's limits

Tags: ios, opengl-es-2.0, shader, fragment-shader, limits

Are some limits of shader's size or variable's number in fragment shader?

I've fragment shader, which returns empty image after some threshold size of code. I think, that problem is in limit of shader's size or number of variables.

I check my shader program after compilation - all is ok.

[Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/3DDrawing/Conceptual/OpenGLES_ProgrammingGuide/BestPracticesforShaders/BestPracticesforShaders.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008793-CH7-SW6) said:

> OpenGL ES limits the number of each variable type you can use in a vertex or fragment shader. The OpenGL ES specification doesn’t require implementations to provide a software fallback when these limits are exceeded; instead, the shader simply fails to compile or link.

[Khronos](https://www.khronos.org/files/opengles_shading_language.pdf) said:

> 2 Length of Shader Executable
>   This is defined by the conformance tests.
>    3 Usage of Temporary Variables
>   The maximum number of variables is defined by the conformance tests.

But I can't find value of this limits.

**UPDATE:**

Sometimes application is interrupted on `glFlush` or `glDrawArrays` with `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`, if image is big.

**SOLVED**

Problem was in too long loop and from whence in long calculation time. Shader is no big, but very complexity.

**UPDATE**

Same problem: [GPUImage Kuwahara filter on iPhone 4S](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24654047/gpuimage-kuwahara-filter-on-iphone-4s)

Comment: I don't think you can query the maximum length. The compilation should fail if you exceed it, though.

Comment: I think, that problem is in the long loop. But I can't do that otherwise. I think, that principally another approach must be implemented here.

Comment: Post your shader.  That's going to be the only way to get help.

Answer (score -1):

If you are checking the results of your shader compilations and linking (like instructed in [Listing 10-1 in Apple's best practices](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/3DDrawing/Conceptual/OpenGLES_ProgrammingGuide/BestPracticesforShaders/BestPracticesforShaders.html).) and there are no errors, something else causes your empty image.

If you are not checking the log, you should start checking :)

Comment: I'm checking log and I sure, that image isn't empty;)

Comment: But you say "which returns empty image after some threshold size of code"? My point was that if the compilation succeeds, then the problem is in the logic of your shader. You cannot query the limits.

Comment: Shader worked successfully with lesser code. But when complexity is increased, complexity of calculation and calculation time are increased too. I think, that OpenGL driver interrupt too long calculations for prevention of hangup.